# How to detect changes to a visual element's built-in properties? - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class *ImageButton: Grid* and would like to detect changes to its *IsEnabled* property. Is there an event-based way to do that?

The *PropertyChanged* event does not appear to be relevant here.

.NET has IsEnabledChanged but that does not seem to be applicable either.

Background: My class implements a clickable image overlaid with text, acting as a button. It's a single-cell Grid housing an Image overlaid with a Label. When an *ImageButton* object is disabled I need to decrease the opacity of the Label and the Image. Of course I could simply add a property to do this but then not able to easily use the class as a drop-in to existing code that uses Button.

Side note: It's a bit puzzling that Button does not offer a BackgroundImage property - must be needed by so many devs.

Comment: I believe, unless I understood badly what you're looking for, that PropertyChanged is actually what you need, as PropertyChangedEventArgs provide you with the name of the Property which have changed : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs/

Comment: Probably related https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20040/disabled-button-style ...they use the `PropertyChanged` event and an extra style in order to accomplish something very similar...check NinoStella's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply **override `OnPropertyChanged` on parent control** to update inner control(s):

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    if(propertyName == nameof(IsEnabled))
    {
         //update controls here
         ...
    }
}
```

---

But I would rather recommend that you **use a converter while binding your inner control's `Opacity` to parent's `IsEnabled` property**.

For example, if you defined your custom control in C#, you can define bindings as:

```
public class ImageButton : Grid
{
    private static readonly BooleanToOpacityConverter _converter = new BooleanToOpacityConverter();
    public ImageButton()
    {
        var label = new Label { Text = "ImageButton" };
        var image = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromFile("icon.png") };

        // add binding to Opacity using IsEnabled from parent
        label.SetBinding(OpacityProperty, new Binding("IsEnabled", converter: _converter, source: this));
        image.SetBinding(OpacityProperty, new Binding("IsEnabled", converter: _converter, source: this));

        ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection { new ColumnDefinition(), new ColumnDefinition() };

        SetColumn(label, 1);
        Children.Add(label);
        Children.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Or, in case you are using XAML based custom control, you can assign your bindings as:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UpdateSourceTriggerApp"
    x:Name="_parent"
    x:Class="UpdateSourceTriggerApp.ImageButton2">
 <Grid.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <local:BooleanToOpacityConverter x:Key="_converter" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
 </Grid.Resources>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition />
   <ColumnDefinition />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Image Source="icon.png" Opacity="{Binding Source={x:Reference _parent}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource _converter}}" />
 <Label Text="ImageButton2" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="{Binding Source={x:Reference _parent}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource _converter}}" />
</Grid>
```

A sample converter would look like:

```
public class BooleanToOpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isEnabled = (value == null) ? false : (bool)value;
        return isEnabled ? 1 : 0.5;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the binding approach @Sharada Gururaj. Works perfectly, many thanks!